# outerwidth and width returns wrong value in firefox relative to chrome

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the width of an element using `element.outerWidth`. When I'm using Chrome it returns a correct value, but when I'm switching to firefox I got a much lower value. In what way does firefox read this element different from chrome?

Element:

```
<div class="submit_container">
     <input type="submit" value="Something" />
</div>
```

Chrome: 88px
Firefox: 36px

When I inspect the element using firefox it display the same with as in chrome. (88px)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023088/wrong-width-calculation-using-outerwidth-in-google-chrome-onload

Comment: The css is loaded long before I'm using outerWidth but I'm adding the submit_container right before I'm checking outerWidth.

Comment: I can not tell why but there is clearly some difference. Have a look at the Metrics tab after selecting the element. If you go to Layout in Firefox it shows something different but it should show the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using jQuery width?

```
$(element).width();
```

It has a slight difference but I guess it's a cross-browser issue.

**EDIT:**

I think the `line-spacing` was the one causing the difference in width. Try removing it in Firefox and you'll see the difference

Comment: Yes, I´ve got the same problem with jQuery width.

Comment: can you post a fiddle of this?

Comment: Ofc. Here I got a jsfiddle, but here it´s just a slight diffrence between them. http://jsfiddle.net/LTbZz/4/

Comment: I think its indeed a crossbrowser issue. I've updated my post

Comment: line-spacing may be one factor in my jsfiddle but in the original problem firefox doens´t even return half of the width that chrome returns.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle on this with the exact content so I could examine it?